# One to Many Relationship Laravel cannot display the related data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, one-to-many, laravel-7

I have two models called `DataKelurahan` and `RegistrasiPasien` and have a one-to-many relationship, but I can't access the relationship.

I have made a form for adding patient and save it to the `registrasi_pasiens` table and it works well. but when I try to display the relation data, it doesn't work properly.

In the `registrasi_pasiens` table, I have 1 record with `kelurahan_id = 3`. Then, I try to access it via `php artisan tinker` with these command:

1. `$kelurahan = App\Domain\DataKelurahan\Models\DataKelurahan::find(3)` works fine and data is exist.
2. `$pasien = App\Domain\RegistrasiPasien\Models\RegistrasiPasien::find(2007000001)` works fine and the data is exist with `kelurahan_id = 3`
3. `$kelurahan->pasiens` the result is `null`. Shouldn't it show the pasien data that has kelurahan_id = 3?
4. `$kelurahan->pasiens->nama` and the result is like this `PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'nama' of non-object in D:/PROFESSIONAL/PROJECT/WEB DEVSeval()'d code on line 1 => null`

I don't have any idea what's wrong with my codes. Much appreciate for your help guys.

Below are the models that I have made:

**DataKelurahan.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Domain\DataKelurahan\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Domain\RegistrasiPasien\Models\RegistrasiPasien;

class DataKelurahan extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['nama_kelurahan', 'nama_kecamatan','nama_kota'];
  public function pasiens(){
    return $this->hasMany('RegistrasiPasien');
  }
}
```

**RegistrasiPasien.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Domain\RegistrasiPasien\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Domain\DataKelurahan\Models\DataKelurahan;

class RegistrasiPasien extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'nama',
      'alamat',
      'telepon',
      'rt',
      'rw',
      'tgl_lahir',
      'jenis_kelamin'
    ];

    public function kelurahan(){
      return $this->belongsTo('DataKelurahan');
    }
}
```

And below are my database tables:

**data_kelurahans**

```
Schema::create('data_kelurahans', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('nama_kelurahan');
   $table->string('nama_kecamatan');
   $table->string('nama_kota');
   $table->timestamps();
});
```

**registrasi_pasiens**

```
Schema::create('registrasi_pasiens', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->integer('kelurahan_id')->unsigned();
   $table->string('nama');
   $table->string('alamat');
   $table->char('telepon', 15);
   $table->integer('rt');
   $table->integer('rw');
   $table->date('tgl_lahir');
   $table->string('jenis_kelamin');
   $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('registrasi_pasiens', function (Blueprint $table){
   $table->foreign('kelurahan_id')->references('id')->on('data_kelurahans')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many):

> Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column on
> the model. By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case"
> name of the owning model and suffix it with `_id`.

So, Eloquent probably got your foreign key name wrong so you must override the foreign key by passing additional arguments to the `hasMany`/`belongsTo` method:

```
public function pasiens(){
  return $this->hasMany('RegistrasiPasien','kelurahan_id');
}

public function kelurahan(){
  return $this->belongsTo('DataKelurahan','kelurahan_id');
}
```